# How can I get IMFVideoDisplayControl from IMFPMediaPlayer?

Tags: windows, winapi, ms-media-foundation

I want to configure some output options in my `IMFPMediaPlayer`. AFAICS, this is possible using the `IMFVideoDisplayControl` interface. However, I don't understand how I can actually get a `IMFVideoDisplayControl` handle for my `IMFPMediaPlayer`. MSDN says the following:

> To get a pointer to the interface, call IMFGetService::GetService. The
> service identifier is GUID MR_VIDEO_RENDER_SERVICE. Call GetService on
> any of the following objects:
>
> The Media Session, if the topology contains an instance of the EVR.
>
> The EVR media sink.
>
> The DirectShow EVR filter.
>
> The EVR presenter.

I don't see `IMFPMediaPlayer` here in that list so I'm wondering how I should get the `IMFVideoDisplayControl` interface from my `IMFPMediaPlayer`. Anybody here who can help?

Comment: This API was deprecated before it was even adopted. If you really need this to be working maybe you could put your code on github and share as something debuggable.

Comment: What's kind of output option do you want to set by using [`IMFVideoControlDisplay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/evr/nn-evr-imfvideodisplaycontrol)?  Since [`IMFPMediaPlayer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfplay/nn-mfplay-imfpmediaplayer) and `IMFVideoDisplayControl` share some functions like `SetBorderColor` and `SetAspectRatioMode`. Maybe there is a workaround.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT: I need to use the `SetVideoPosition` method. AFAICS, this is not available in `IMFPMediaPlayer` so I need to find a way to get an `IMFVideoDisplayControl` for my `IMFPMediaPlayer`....

Comment: @RomanR.: So are you saying that it is impossible to get a `IMFVideoDisplayControl` from `IMFPMediaPlayer` or is it just that nobody really knows how to do that because `IMFPMediaPlayer` never became a widely used API?

Comment: I meant the latter. I gave a quick look at the API and it looks like access to internal EVR is impossible, not at least directly. The API is obviously using EVR internally and has this interface but it's the whole point of the higher level API to manage EVR internally and prevent from direct access across the layer. Since almost noone used this API in real life it would be hard to find a mentioned workaround and it could be even gray area  which simply never received proper attention, then API was deprecated.

Comment: @RomanR.: That's a pity. I was really happy about the `IMFPMediaPlayer` API because just a few lines of code were needed to play a video. No idea why they deprecated it. It's definitely very user friendly to get into it. The Media Session API OTOH looks much more complicated and needs lots of more code just to play a video :(

Comment: @Andreas Video source rectangle can be set by [`IMFPMediaPlayer::SetVideoSourceRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfplay/nf-mfplay-imfpmediaplayer-setvideosourcerect). You can found that `IMFPMediaPlayer` had [`SetVideoPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd374365(v%3Dvs.85)) function but no longer exist anymore. So it is suggested to use new API like `IMFVideoDisplayControl` in new application development to avoid of issues caused by API removed.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT: I need to set the video destination rectangle so `SetVideoSourceRect` doesn't help, I'm afraid.

Comment: [`IMFPMediaPlayer` is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/media-foundation-interfaces). For playing back, it is suggested to use [Media Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/media-session) instead.